# Writing a formula into a cell with VBA creates extra parenthesis

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm creating a macro that writes a formula into a cell. However, the formula that appears in the cell after the run is adding a parenthesis.

This is the code:

```
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Parameters!A:B,2,0)"
```

This is the formula in the cell after run:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2305,Parameters!A:(B),2,0)
```

It is adding a *parenthesis* in `B` column.
Can you please help me fix this code.

Comment: Just a side note: Try avoid using `.select` to make your code better and faster. Read [VBA Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices) to see how.

Answer (score 5):

You are taking "the best of the two worlds" and Excel does not like it! :)
E.g., you are using RC and letters notation. Thus, Excel changes a bit your formula.

Something like this should work:

`Selection.formula = "=VLOOKUP(D47,Parameters!A:B,2,0)"`

Or something like this, if you make it in RC:

`Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Parameters!C[-4]:C[-3],2,0)`

`Selection.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Parameters!C[-4]:C[-3],2,0)`

(Both `Selection.Formula` and `Selection.Formular1c1` work)
Here you can see more about RC formulas:

- [Excel Easy - FormulaR1C1](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/formulaR1C1.html)
- [Better Solutions - A1 or R1C1 Notation](http://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm)

Comment: Shouldn't the second example be `Selection.FormulaR1C1 = ...`

Comment: @Jeeped - actually they both work. Anyhow, I have edited it.

Comment: They both work because VBA's overhead sees the formula as unambiguous. If there were only references like `RC1` that could mean row 1, column RC in xlA1 or the current row, column A in xlR1C1. Best to avoid situations that potentially *could* be ambiguous in a learning atmosphere.